# Запретить ввод знаков препинания в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть калькулятор, который принимает значеия из input-ов и затем производить необходимые математические вычисления. У каждого из инпутов `type = "number"`, все работает нормально, но при вводе `.`, `-` перестает работает, значение отдает как пустое в консоль. С `,` работает все нормально.
Попытался прописать `pattern="\d+(,\d{2})?"`, но видимо не разобрался как он работает и ничего он мне не дал.
Мне нужно запретить ввод .`и`-`, ну и был бы признателен, если бы объяснили как ограничить ввод до 2 знаков после`,`, чтобы выглядело как цена.
Спасибо
Вот моя функция и врестка

```js
$('.calculator-button').on('click', function(){
    var calculator = {
        priceGbo: $('#price_gbo').val(),
        priceFuel: $('#price_fuel').val(),
        priceGas: $('#price_gas').val(),
        priceMile: $('#expenses_mile').val(),
        priceDay: $('#expenses_day').val()
    };

    var everydayEconomy = calculator.priceDay * (calculator.priceMile/100) * (calculator.priceFuel - calculator.priceGas * 1.1);
    var fiveYears = everydayEconomy * 1825;
    var feedbackTime = calculator.priceGbo / everydayEconomy;

    $('#everyday_economy').text(everydayEconomy.toFixed(0));
    $('#fiveYears_economy').text(fiveYears.toFixed(0));
    $('#feedback_time').text(feedbackTime.toFixed(0));

});
```

```css
.call-modal {
 width: 377px;
 height: 50px;
 background: #ffc107;
 color: black;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "Pt Sans Bold";
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: center;
         justify-content: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "calculator-inputs-left">
  <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row">
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__text">Цена ГБО (грн.)</div>
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__input">
          <input type = "number" pattern="\d+(,\d{2})?" class = "calculator-input" id = "price_gbo" min="0" value = "">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row">
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__text">Цена 1Л. бензина (грн.)</div>
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__input">
          <input type = "number" class = "calculator-input" id = "price_fuel" min="0" value = "">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row">
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__text">Цена 1Л. газа (грн.)</div>
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__input">
          <input type = "number" class = "calculator-input" id = "price_gas" min="0" value = "">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row">
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__text">Расход на 100 км пробега (л)</div>
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__input">
          <input type = "number" class = "calculator-input" id = "expenses_mile" min="0" value = "">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row">
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__text">Средний суточный пробег (км)</div>
      <div class = "calculator-inputs-left-row__input">
          <input type = "number" class = "calculator-input" id = "expenses_day" min="0" value = "">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class = "call-modal calculator-button">Получить результат</div>
  <div class = "calculator-line"></div>
  <div class = "calculator-results">
      <div class = "calculator-results-item">
          <div class = "calculator-results-item__text">Ежедневная экономия (грн.)</div>
          <div class = "calculator-results-item__result" >
              <span id = "everyday_economy"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "calculator-results-item">
          <div class = "calculator-results-item__text">За 5 лет экплуатации (грн.)</div>
          <div class = "calculator-results-item__result">
              <span id = "fiveYears_economy"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "calculator-results-item">
          <div class = "calculator-results-item__text">Срок окупаемости (дней)</div>
          <div class = "calculator-results-item__result">
              <span id = "feedback_time"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно что запретить

Comment: я тоже не понял, запретить знак "-" значит запретить отрицательные цисла?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
через регулярки пишите паттерн который нужен

```
    $('input[type="number"]').on('keyup focus', (event) => {
        let select = $(event.currentTarget);
        select.val(select.val().replace(/[^0-9]/gi,'').replace(/\s+/gi,', '))
        + console.log( '#: '+select.val() );
    });
```

> если бы объяснили как ограничить ввод до 2 знаков посл
>   я бы сюда сходил https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/#examples

Answer (score 1):

Атрибут `pattern` задает выражение для валидации данных при `submit`'e формы. То есть, такая проверка и не должна срабатывать при вводе каждого символа. Плюс, она не фильтрует ввод.

Для решения вашей задачи, необходимо написать скрипт, который:

1. либо будет проверять `validity.valid` элемента, сообщая пользователю что он накриворучил

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test'); 
test.addEventListener('input', function () {
  if (this.validity.valid)
    this.classList.remove('err'); 
  else 
    this.classList.add('err'); 
});
```

```css
#test.err { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<input id="test" type="number" pattern="^\d+(?:,\d{0,2})?$">
```

2. либо, полностью реализует всю логику проверки/фильтрации

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', pInpInit);

function pInpInit() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-regexp'); 
  for (let inp of inputs) {
    inp.addEventListener('input', onPInpInput); 
    inp.addEventListener('click', function () {
      this.lastCaretPos = this.selectionStart;
    }); 
  }
}

function onPInpInput() {
  if (!this.value.length) {
    this.lastValue = ''; 
    return; 
  }
  let regxpr = this.dataset.regexp; 
  if (!regxpr) 
    return; 
  regxpr = new RegExp(regxpr, 'i'); 
  if (this.value.match(regxpr)) {
    this.lastValue = this.value; 
    this.lastCaretPos = this.selectionStart;
  } else {
    this.value = this.lastValue || ''; 
    let pos = this.lastCaretPos || 0; 
    this.setSelectionRange(pos, pos); 
    this.classList.remove('anim'); 
    requestAnimationFrame(() =>  this.classList.add('anim')); 
  }
}
```

```css
body { padding: 30vh 50px; }

@keyframes color-fade {
    0% { background-color: #f002; }
   50% { background-color: #f002; }
  100% { background-color: initial; }
}

.input-regexp {
  width: 150px; 
  text-align: center; 
  font: 20px sans-serif; 
}
.input-regexp.anim { animation: color-fade 0.5s linear; }
```

```html
<input class="input-regexp" type="text" data-regexp="^\d+(?:,\d{0,2})?$">&emsp;
<input class="input-regexp" type="text" data-regexp="^\d+(?:[,.]\d{0,2})?$">
```

Во втором примере, левый инпут принимает в качестве разделителя только запятую, а правый - и запятую, и точку.