# Запрет ввода элемента javascript

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Есть просто калькулятор на JavaScript, как сделать ограничение чтоб точку один раз вводить можно было? А то ввести можно 78.....10
Сильно не ругайте, лишь изучаю

Comment: дак для этого есть `parseDouble, parseFloat`. и поиск в строке. Если более одной точки. просто не пускать или отсеивать ну и замечательная функция `toFixed()`.

Comment: Учитывайте что способ решения через `keypress` и `keydown` (варианты которого предлагаются в ответах здесь) - не работают как минимум в некоторых мобильных браузерах. Можно решить это, но более объемным кодом, по принципу "сохраняем последние значение и позицию, и если юзер вводит 'запретное' - восстанавливаем их". Пример смотрите в этом ответе (пример кода №2): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810850/288409

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```js
input.onkeypress = e => !(e.key === "." && ~input.value.indexOf("."))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" >
```

Мы следим за событием `onkeypress`, когда оно срабатывает мы проверяем какой символ, `e.key === "."`, и если в этом поле уже имеется этот символ `~input.value.indexOf(".")`, то делаем `return false`, и наш символ не добавляется в поле.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    if (e.key === '.' && input.value.indexOf('.') >= 0) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: В мобильном хроме это не работает, к сожалению.