# Валидация input с проверкой на максимальное значение

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как валидировать input на ходу. Например если вводимое число больше 50, то не давать ввести последнюю цифру.

```
$('input').on('change input keyup', function (e) {
   if ( $(this).val() > 50 ) {
       return false;
   }
}
```

Такое не срабатывает - символ уже введен, и ввод не отменить. А если проверять по keypress или keydown, то содержимое input не проверить.

Как решить такую задачу?

Comment: Почему не проверить, что вы пробовали для этого?

Comment: `<input type="number" max="50">`

Comment: О том как реализовать валидацию при вводе, можете посмотреть в этом ответе (сниппет №2): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810850/288409

Comment: @RomanC если проверять по keydown или keypress, то проверяется предыдущее значение input, без учета только что введенного символа

Answer (score 0):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('in');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value > 50) {
    let arr = this.value.split('');
    arr = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
    this.value = arr.join('');
  }
})
```

Comment: Это совсем не универсально. Пользователь же может вводить цифры не только в конце, но и в середине, и в начале